# What is the best category to ask questions about algorithms(C,PHP...)?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm learning algorithms in C, and I want to know what is the best category here on Stack Exchange to ask questions about **introductory algorithms(those who are usually left as exercises in introductory CS courses**.)

I don't want things like; "Theoretical computer science","Artificial Intelligence".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask them on sites like [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) if the questions are formatted properly to be on-topic there.

> those who are usually left as exercises in introductory CC courses.

To be noted that homework questions from classes are heavily discouraged in almost all the SO communities. However, if they are exercises from a book which you are self-studying from, then it is okay.